# How to dynamically increment the limit on a collection cursor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm currently trying to implement a "Load more" button on a simple news page.

I've got the search working, thanks to [Meteor Chef](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/simple-search/), and I followed the same principles to implement a "Load more" button. The relevant code is as follows:

Template:

```
Template.listAllNews.onCreated(function() {
  template.limit = new ReactiveVar(10);
  Tracker.autorun( () => {
    template.subscribe( 'news.all', template.searchQuery.get(), template.limit.get(), () => {
      setTimeout( () => {
        template.searching.set( false );
      }, 300 );
    });
  });


Template.listAllNews.events({
  'click .load-more-button': function (event, template) {
    var limit = template.limit.get();
    limit += 10;
    template.limit.set( limit );
  }
});
```

Publication:

```
let query      = {},
    projection = { limit: limit, sort: { submitted: -1 } };

if ( search ) {
  let regex = new RegExp( search, 'i' );
  query = {
    $or: [
      { title: regex }
    ]
  };
  projection.limit = 100;
}
return News.find( query, projection );
```

This works. The problem is: it refreshes all the data instead of just loading the extra 10 news articles. I want it to only load the extra 10 articles upon click, and not to "refresh" the subscription.

How can I do that?

Comment: Instead of increasing limit, skip can be used?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how that would help me achieve my goal of infinite scrolling. What do you have in mind?